# Roomba 700 series

Tags: ros, roomba

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the last couple of months, I have been playing with a Tegra TK1 and learning ROS. I have an old 700 series Roomba that I want to use with ROS. It has the DIN/serial connection, right under the handle, but I was wondering if anyone has tried the using 700 series Roombas with ROS before? Or if they know otherwise the the tools available for the 500 series will work for the 700?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221112/roomba-700-series/) by [MechanicalMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25116/mechanicalman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working on a driver for iRobot Create 1 and Create 2 (aka. Roomba 500 and 600 series). The relevant interface for the 500 series is basically a subset of the 600 series, with the exception of odometry which is computed different because of firmware bugs in the 600 series. Hopefully, the same holds true for the 700 series. I would be really interested in knowing how the driver fairs with the 700 series. You can find the driver here: http://wiki.ros.org/create_autonomy

If we're lucky it will just work :)

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechanicalMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25116/mechanicalman/) on 2016-04-05**:
I will give it a test and let you know. Might take a few days though, changing jobs and the on-boarding process is kind of intense.

**Comment by [MechanicalMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25116/mechanicalman/) on 2016-04-10**:
I can't even seem to get this run. Its possible that its on my end - I am trying to run this on a Tegra TK1 - but I do not think so. Opening a new question here.